# hibernate mapping for Object

Tags: hibernate

```
public class ID {
    protected String name;
    protected Object id;
}
```

How can I map the above class in hibernate, if I were to use `ID.hbm.xml` ? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using xml, you can use annotations:

```
@Entity
public class ID {
    @Id
    private Object id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Btw, `ID` is a strange name for an entity.

In XML you would need something like this ([reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html)):

```
<class ...>
    <id .. />
    <property .. />
</class>
```

The type of the `id` field depends entirely on your requirements - most often it is an auto-generated `int` (using the `@GeneratedValue` annotation). But it can be a `String`, or any manually-assigned, database-persistable type.

Comment: I know its is weired, what should be the type ? <class name="ID" table="ID">
        <id name="id" type="???">
            <column name="id" />
        </id>
        ............
    </class>

Comment: The ID type depends on you - it can be int, long or anything.